# Concrete example illustrating equivalence of two definitions of pushforward

Tags: vectors, partial-derivative, pushforward

In manifold analysis, there are two definitions of pushforward of vectors on Euclidean spaces. Let $\phi$ be a map from $M$ to $N$, which are subsets of two Euclidean spaces. Then the pushforward of $\phi$, denoted $\phi_*$, can be defined "concretely" as the Jacobian of $\phi$, denoted $D(\phi)$. Given a vector $v$ on $M$, expressed as a column matrix, one can then calculate $\phi_*v$ by doing matrix multiplication $D(\phi)v$.

However, $\phi_*$ can also be defined "abstractly" as follows: given a vector $v$ on $M$, which is seen as a partial differentiation operator on real-valued functions on $M$, $\phi_*$ can be seen as an operator transforming $v$ to $\phi_*v$, which is a partial differentiation operator on real-valued functions on $N$ such that if $f$ is any real-valued function on $N$, then we have $\phi_*v(f) = v(f \circ \phi)$.

Can anybody give a concrete example illustrating the equivalence of these two definitions?

Comment: The second definition is the coordinate free version. So if you express the second definition in terms of coordinates, then you get the first definition you mentioned. This is done in all standard textbooks so it shouldn't be hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion given, I now give an example. Let $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3; \phi(x, y) = (u, v, w)$ such that $u = x + y, v = x - y, w = xy$, $v = [v_1, v_2]^T$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ expressed as a column vector, $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}; f(u, v, w) = uvw$. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi_* = D(\phi) = \left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 \\
y  & x
\end{array} \right]
\end{eqnarray*}
And so
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi_*v & = & \left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 \\
y  & x
\end{array} \right]\left[\begin{array}{r}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{array} \right] \\
& = & \left[\begin{array}{c}
v_1 + v_2 \\
v_1 - v_2 \\
v_1y + v_2x
\end{array} \right] \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Then we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi_*v(f) & = & \left((v_1 + v_2)\frac{\partial}{\partial u} + (v_1 - v_2)\frac{\partial}{\partial v} + (v_1y + v_2x)\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\right)(uvw) \\
& = & (v_1 + v_2)vw + (v_1 - v_2)uw + (v_1y + v_2x)uv \\
& = & (v_1 + v_2)(x - y)(xy) + (v_1 - v_2)(x + y)(xy) + (v_1y + v_2x)(x + y)(x - y) \\
& = & v_1(3x^2y - y^3) + v_2(x^3 - 3xy^2)
\end{eqnarray*}

On the other hand, since $f \circ \phi(x, y) = x^3y - xy^3$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
v(f \circ \phi) & = & \left(v_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + v_2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)(x^3y - xy^3) \\
& = & v_1(3x^2y - y^3) + v_2(x^3 - 3xy^2)
\end{eqnarray*}
We have thus verified that $\phi_*v(f) = v(f \circ \phi)$.